# Facebook Login and redirect not happening properly

Tags: android, android-intent

When ever I login into my android app which is hooked with facebook login (enabled SSO) it automatically gets login in to my app with out as me to enter login credentials . Here is my code plz help me out I dnt knw the reason .Why this is happening in app

```
package ten.mob.socialapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

public class FoodStarLoginActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String faceBookAppId = "430255993683523";
    static Facebook facebook = new Facebook(faceBookAppId);
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner;
    Context context;
    String logout = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null){
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0){
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()){
            logInAuthorization();
        }
        Intent getintent = getIntent();
        logout=getintent.getStringExtra("logout");
        if(logout == null && facebook.isSessionValid()){
            startSearchMyActivity();
        }else{
            facebookLogout();
            if(!facebook.isSessionValid()){
                logInAuthorization();
                if(facebook.isSessionValid())
                    startSearchMyActivity();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void facebookLogout() {
        try{
            facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startSearchMyActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SearchMyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void logInAuthorization(){
        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error){}
            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e){}
            @Override
            public void onCancel(){}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside facebook authorization method there must be any exception..
try to resolve this